# Is "retard" offensive when used as a verb?

Tags: offensive-language

Obviously calling someone a "retard" or "retarded" is considered offensive.

> As a noun, it is considered a dated, offensive and pejorative term when used to refer to a person who has a mental disability.

-*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retard_(pejorative)*

However, is it offensive when used as a verb?

[image]

Google (Oxford dictionary) labels the noun as offensive, but not the verb.

Comment: There's no objective measure of offensiveness.  Are there people out there who will be offended if you use *retard* as a verb?  Probably.  If dictionaries and such don't describe it as offensive, that probably suggests that it's not widely considered to be offensive.

Comment: @Juhasz Than whats the point of the [offensive-language] tag?

Comment: Likely for these kinds of questions. I just happen to think that in this case, you're not likely to get a better answer than the one the dictionaries provide.

Comment: As I understand it, there are people out there who can be offended by words like ***blackboard*** and ***niggardly***. So there's always *somebody* ready to take offence at *anything*. But your example seems to be on a par with mine - only people with limited grasp of English and/or who aren't very bright are likely to be offended. And without wishing to be *too* offensive, I'd say what such people "think" isn't very important (even though I do respect the fact that they might ***feel*** that way).

Comment: I can't tell if this is an example of trolling or a legitimate question … (If a legitimate question, I think it would make more sense at [ELL](https://english.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: @Jason Could they improve on Juhasz's superb comment 'There's no objective measure of offensiveness. Are there people out there who will be offended if you use _retard_ as a verb? Probably. If dictionaries and such don't describe it as offensive, that probably suggests that it's not widely considered to be offensive,' do you think?

Comment: I think something backfired!

Answer (score 0):

This question is mostly boiled down to opinion or maturity level of the listener.

The word *retard* has many other uses where it is never considered to be offensive.

For example: *fire retardant*

Unfortunately, this use has been tainted by the over-usage of the noun *retard* to describe people who are not *mentally retarded*.  This usage is always always meant to be offensive since it's a comparison of the subject to someone who is mentally retarded.

[*Mental retardation*](https://www.pediatrics.emory.edu/centers/pehsu/health/mental.html) is still a commonly used medical terminology to describe a symptom of many different syndromes.  Due to the negative association, most medical professionals have phased it out in favor of *developmental delay* and *intellectual disability*, or, where appropriate, descriptions of the syndrome itself (*e.g.* Down Syndrome).

There are other words with similar issues.  As FumbleFingers points out in comments above *niggardly* is a prime example.  Its similar sound to the offensive n-word makes it a hard word to use in conversation.

So, in direct answer to your question:  Use the word judiciously. Consider your audience. If using it to describe a process, *Retards the progress of ....* it's fine.  But, I wouldn't say:  *We were retarded on our journey...*. It's just too fraught with issues.

Note in response to comments: this seems to be primarily an American English phenomenon.

Comment: Might be worth noting that even today, using 'retard' to mean 'stupid' has a distinctly American English feel. In British English, the word tends to be used as a transitive verb meaning to slow.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Interesting, I didn't realized this feeling was localized to America.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I speak AmE and cannot speak to the BrE sensibility about it.

Comment: BrE, while aware of the US usage, doesn't use it much so it is unlikely you will offend someone by using a verb that sounds like it. It's also worth noting that the noun has the emphasis on the first syllable, but the verb (at least in BrE) has the emphasis on the second syllable. So there is a distinct difference between them and they are unlikely to be confused.

Comment: @DJClayworth not as reliable of a distinction in AmE

Comment: And this assumes that you are not trying to offend. If you keep talking about how people with mental disabilities "retard" this or that form of progress you will justifiably be held to account.

Comment: It was not unknown in the Britain of my youth (1950s & 60s) to hear 'retarded' used as an adjective about someone who was (another outdated term) 'educationally subnormal (ESN)'. Often used informally to mean 'stupid' or even 'annoying'.  Just the adjective.

Comment: Regarding using disability terms casually, it is also worth noting the US/British division about calling someone who is clumsy a 'spaz', or saying they 'spazzed something up', etc. I understand this is quite OK in the USA; in Britain it is one of the most offensive things you could say, maybe the most.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey This is marginal in the US. It's gaining steam as being offensive similarly to retard.

Comment: In Britain, the charity called the Spastics Society changed its name (to Scope), in 1994.